# How to Export Control Flow Graph in Ghidra？

Tags: ghidra

I want to get the control flow graph of each function. And I can see the control flow graph via the option Window -> Function Graph.

How can I save it as jpg? In addition, does ghidra have a corresponding API to export cfg to png?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, ghidra doesn't have APIs to output graphs into png,jpg,pdf, etc. 

But if you need the png or maybe the jpg of the graph, you can export the graph as "DOT" and write a python script to get the format you want.